# Which island in the Maldives should we stay to see the 'sea of stars' and also do all activities!

Tags: identify-this, locate-this, resorts, maldives

My husband and I are thinking to go to the Maldives for our honeymoon. So I was searching places to visit in the Maldives; I got a list of places and things to do. After more research I came to know this thing, which is very interesting but not mentioned or listed anywhere unless you research it.

I came to know about the "[Sea of Stars.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/is-the-sea-of-stars-real)". According to this post I can see it from two places 1. Reethi Beach and 2. Vaadhoo Islands. Now my question is this true? In an article I read you can see it on any island of the Maldives.

So now I'm confused: what should I do, or which resort is good to visit all the good places in the Maldives, all the activities, best views and of course "sea of stars"?

Edit::

Which island in the Maldives should we stay at to see the 'sea of stars' and also do all activities?

**There are many island in Maldives which have so many resorts how to choose best island to stay for all activities!!!**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This phenomenon (bioluminescent phytoplankton) is a random one if I remember correctly. So just a hotel selection might not guarantee you witnessing it. It also depends on other factors such as time of the year etc.

Comment: Also be aware that the photos you see are long exposures and digitally enhanced. Reality would be quite underwhelming.